# SQL constraint with UNIQUE and CHECK

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique, ddl

My goal is to prevent an INSERT if an "address" with the same "account_id" as "is_principal" true (I want only one is_principal address by account).

Is there a way to create an SQL constraint with UNIQUE and CHECK ?

I try this :

```
ALTER TABLE address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_account_adresses2_idx UNIQUE(account_id, CHECK (is_principal >= 1));
```

ERROR :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHECK (is_principal >= 1))' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_compte_adresses2_idx UNIQUE(account_id, CHECK (is_principal >= 1));)
```

Thanks.

EDIT :

INSERT examples who should works :

```
insert into `address` (`address`, `account_id`, `is_principal`) values (address 1, 1, 1);
insert into `address` (`address`, `account_id`, `is_principal`) values (address 2, 1, 0);
insert into `address` (`address`, `account_id`, `is_principal`) values (address 3, 1, 0);
```

INSERT examples who should fail :

```
insert into `address` (`address`, `account_id`, `is_principal`) values (address 1, 1, 1);
insert into `address` (`address`, `account_id`, `is_principal`) values (address 2, 1, 1);
```

Comment: I'd guess you need separate UNIQUE and CHECK constraints.

Comment: *I want only one is_principal address by account* Does you want to allow any amount of records with the same `account_id` and `is_principal` treated as FALSE (NULL, zero, empty string) and only one with `is_principal` treated as TRUE (non-empty string or non-zero number)?

Comment: yes exactly @Akina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
ALTER TABLE address 
ADD COLUMN for_check INT AS (CASE WHEN is_principal 
                                  THEN account_id 
                                  END) VIRTUAL,
ADD CONSTRAINT check_only_one_principal_address 
    UNIQUE INDEX (for_check);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc8e4a0aa116779095baccf1de0951c1)

Generated column generates `account_id` value for a record with `is_principal = TRUE` and `NULL` in another case. NULLs are not checked in UNIQUE constraint.

Virtual generated column does not need in additional disk space.

Applicable for MySQL starting from the version 5.7.8 (if you do not specify VIRTUAL and use a static, STORED, column, then from 5.7.6).

Comment: YES ! Thanks @Akina

Answer (score 0):

Use comma separated syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE address ADD CONSTRAINT fk_account_adresses2_idx UNIQUE(account_id),
                    ADD CHECK (is_principal >= 1);
```

As a side note, check constraints in versions of MySQL earlier than 8+ will be ignored.  So, if you are using an earlier version of MySQL, then the check constraint would be ignored.

Comment: Hello Tim, 
Your code is creating a UNIQUE constraint for "account_id" but i want that an account is able to save multiple addresses. Your code give me this error :
```SQL
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'fk_compte_adresses2_idx' 
```

Comment: Add sample data to your question then.